# Why does ^C, ^V etc. appear in the terminal when I use the Ctrl+character keyboard shortcut?

Tags: command-line

Sometimes, when copy-pasting text from the output of commands, I'll accidently use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

So the command-line interprets it as `^C`...

Why is this? Why does the command-line interpret <kbd>control</kbd> input as `^`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It does not actually insert the character sequence "^C". This is only a representation for unprintable ASCII control characters, such as:

- `^C` → ETX (End of text, sends a kill signal), ASCII 0x03
- `^D` → EOT (End of transmission, terminates input), ASCII 0x04
- `^H` → BS (Backspace, `\b`), ASCII 0x08
- `^J` → LF (Line feed, `\n`), ASCII 0x0A
- `^L` → FF (Form feed, new page, clears the terminal), ASCII 0x0C
- `^M` → CR (Carriage return, `\r`), ASCII 0x0D

This is only a small extract of possible ASCII control characters that can be inserted using the keyboard; you can find a full list [here](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/c0.html).

I think the most important ones to remember are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: The use of the caret `^` as a symbol for "control" dates back to pre-graphic times when terminals were text-only, and I believe even before then when we had cards and paper, no terminals. I'd love to know _why_ the caret was chosen as the symbol.

Answer (score 8):

Because <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>KEY</kbd> combos are interpreted by the terminal as non-printable ASCII characters, and being those non-printable you need a way to represent them.

The convention, stemming from [VT terminals with ANSI support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), is to represent the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>KEY</kbd> combo representing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with a caret (`^`) and <kbd>KEY</kbd> with <kbd>KEY</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

When copying and pasting to/from a terminal, it is best practise to use the short cuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> respectively.

These are the more traditional short cuts for terminal use, though you'll note that in an X graphical environment <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> are tied to the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

In most terminals <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (represented by `^C`) are used to halt the execution of a process, hence pasting with that short cut won't work.

For quick copying and pasting, you can utilize X's primary buffer by highlighting whatever text you want to copy, and then middle-clicking where you want to paste it. No keyboard required.

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood the question. OP wanted to know why the string `^C` or similar ones appear when pressing CTRL+C (or CTRL+ another letter). It's not about how to correctly copy and paste stuff in the terminal, for which your answer would be great.

Comment: @ByteCommander, right you are! my apologies, I'll leave my answer as is however, as it seems the question has been properly answered already :) Someone might stumble across this and find what I wrote useful.

Answer (score -2):

You *should* be using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and not <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, because on the command line, they do the same thing (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is easier than <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).  That might not be true in certain graphical environments where the GUI captures some keystrokes and does something special, but if the keystrokes are truly sent to the command line, then there is no difference.  This is why pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> may show ^C as a capital C, instead of a lowercase C.  The command line makes no distinction on which one you pressed (and uppercase was presumably judged to be easier to read).  This is true for letters; for other characters, the <kbd>Shift</kbd> may have an effect.)

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> sends the ASCII code that is 64 below the uppercase letter's position in the ASCII table (and 96 less than the lowercase letter's position in the ASCII table).  So pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> (lowercase) sends ASCII code 3 (which is 64 less than capital <kbd>C</kbd>'s ASCII code of 67).  In many environments, you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then press <kbd>3</kbd> on the numpad (and then release the <kbd>3</kbd> key, and then release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key) and you may get the same effect.

Regarding ^C, the ^ is just a well-known shorthand for the "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>" key.  Similarly, M- is a shorthand for the "<kbd>Alt</kbd>" key.  Err, yeah.  M stands for the word "Meta", which can be entered by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing whatever comes next, or sometimes by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> (and releasing <kbd>Esc</kbd>) and then pressing whatever comes next.  [Wikipedia's article on "Control Key": "Notation" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key#Notation) describes this as "Traditional notation".  This is also known as Caret Notation ([Wikipedia's article on Caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation), [Unix StackExchange: ryvnf's question about Caret Notation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226329/is-ctrl4-equal-to-4-or-in-caret-notation)).

Regarding the last question, the command shell is not "interpreting" anything to be a caret.  In other words, the shell is not reading anything, and believing that it is a caret.  What is happening is that the shell is using the well-known caret notation for output.  As another example, you can see the well-known pager, "less", use caret notation by running: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=64 count=1 | less`

(The "nano" text editor also uses caret notation in its online help, including the full screens of online help shown after pressing ^G, a.k.a. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>.)

Comment: DevRobot is specifically asking about using Ctrl-C (or rather Shift-Ctrl-C) in the context of copy and paste, which implies a GUI terminal. You're not necessarily incorrect, but you're explanation is definitely confusing for someone coming from a GUI-user perspective.