# System automatically writes ^@ in the terminal

Tags: keyboard

I don't know why but when I switch to non graphical mode, the system starts writing ^@ continuously and i'm not pressing that keys.

Comment: Check if any key got stuck, press them down one by one to make sure the key properly releases. Beside that no clue.

Comment: Nope, I tried restarting it, pressing the keys and starting Ubuntu with recovery mode.

Comment: If it helps, it looks like `^@` represents a NUL char (U+0), according to [this table](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm) (from here: [Why does ^C, ^V etc. appear in the terminal when I use the Ctrl+character keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/q/704600/301745))

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Search and replace control characters (^@, ^M, ^I…) in vi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/217010/117037)

Comment: So I don't know why but the system is printing null and because of that I can't write without interruptions.

Comment: You might have accidentally redirected /dev/zero to a standard stream (i.e. stdin, stdout, or stderr), but I have no idea how that would happen.